# How to solve: Error: Unable to initialize main class com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner

Tags: linux, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

Hey guys I'm trying to run Dynamodb with serverless locally executing the following command: `sls dynamodb start --migrate --stage local`

And I get an error:
[image]

Before that I installed with this `sls dynamodb install --stage local`  and everything seems ok.

I take a look if the problems is the port but isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary: perhaps try deleting `.dynamodb` and re-initializing.

Situation: I ran into this same error while testing my developer startup instructions in a second directory, where everything was working fine in the first one. In comparing the two directories, I found significant differences between the two `.dynamodb` directories, indicating that the install / initialization had failed. So I simply deleted the `.dynamodb` in the new location and re-initialized DynamoDB local. Solved the problem.

Comment: In my case, I needed re-initializing too.

Comment: Re-initialize it by deleting .dynamodb from the repository and adding it to .gitignore. In CI/CD (Bitbucket in my case) execute 2 commands: 1. npm install 2. sls dynamodb install.
Docker container:  nik0lay/serverless-framework:node14-jre11